# How to improve performance by getting multiple images in a single http request?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am creating a website in `AngularJs(1.5.5)` that has a lot of images on the page. To show these images I make one http request per image. So is there a way to get all the images by making a single http request?

I am aware of css sprites and I can't use that as there are lot of images like employee images of a company and can't create sprite for these.

There is a node server running from which the images are retrieved.

Comment: Only request the images when they are viewed. There are javascript plugins for that [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTTP/2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2).

It will not allow you to request multiple images in a single request, but it will keep the connection open to the web server and allow multiplexing of multiple image requests.

Answer (score 0):

Without using CSS sprites, the only single request option I can think of would be to base 64 encode the images and include them as data urls in the HTML. This would technically reduce them to 0 calls to the webserver!

Now whether vastly increasing the size of the HTML to reduce the number of server requests is worth it is something I couldn't answer without more information about page design etc, so something that you would have to test.

I +1 the suggestion of using HTTP/2 some in browser tests I have seen have it increasing performance 30-400%!

If these options aren't possible, some other things to consider that would help with performance if not directly related to the question:

- Apache/nginx have access to google's pagespeed module that can automatically optimise images, among many other things, maybe there is something similar for node?
- You could use a CDN to increase serving performance. (Especially if you have users that are distributed geographically)
- A large number of images by itself isn't necessarily a reason not to use CSS sprites, depending on how the images are being used, it could be a nice solution to have a server side script that generates the sprites / css for you, as part of the build process, part of the image upload process, or even on demand from the user requests. The extra build time of compiling the images / serving the cached compiled sheet may offer some time savings.